# Trouble saving and displaying form submission data to localStorage

Tags: javascript, json, forms, local-storage

I am trying to create a basic script that takes information from an HTML form and displays it on the page. This project is just to practice the JavaScript functions that I am currently learning through self-study.

Right now submitting the form creates a card on the page that displays the information submitted, and each time the form is submitted a new card is created. However, the challenge I am facing now is that when the page is refreshed, all of the cards disappear.

I am trying to figure out how to use localStorage and have added some basic functions to my code; however I am finding that the cards still disappear when the page is refreshed. My questions are:

1. How can I check whether the data from the form submission is actually being saved somewhere?
2. How can I edit my code to continue to display the existing cards on the page even when the page is refreshed?

Here is my code on [CodePen](https://codepen.io/abigaildawson/pen/ExrjrOy).

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Flashcard Project</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./flashcard_styles.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="form-wrapper">
        <h1 class="form-title">Add a word</h1>
        <form id="vocab-form" method="POST">
            <div class="input-group">
                <label for="word">Word</label>
                <input id="word" name="word" type="text" placeholder="詞彙">
            </div>
            <div class="input-group">
                <label for="meaning">Meaning</label>
                <input id="meaning" name="meaning" type="text" placeholder="vocabulary">
            </div>
            <div class="input-group">
                <label for="notes">Notes</label>
                <textarea id="notes" name="notes" rows="6" cols="30"></textarea>
            </div>
            <button id="submit" type="submit" value="submit">Add</button>
        </form>
    </div>
    <div class="vocab-grid">
    </div>

    <script src="./flashcard_script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

```js
const myVocab = [];

function saveData() {
    localStorage.setItem('myVocab', JSON.stringify(myVocab));
}

function loadData() {
    const storedData = localStorage.getItem('myVocab');
    if(storedData) {
        myVocab.push(...JSON.parse(storedData));
    }
}

loadData();

const form = document.querySelector('form');
const vocabGrid = document.querySelector('.vocab-grid');

// define a constructor function to create vocab objects
function Vocab(word, meaning, notes) {
    this.word = word;
    this.meaning = meaning;
    this.notes = notes;
}

// define a function to add new Vocab to myVocab on form submit click
function addVocab(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    const data = new FormData(event.target);

    let formObj = {}; // initialize empty object to store form values

    // loop thru FormData entried
    for(let [key, value] of data.entries()) {
        formObj[key] = value; // stores the values with their keys within the formObj object
    }

    // convert the stored formObj to a more useful newVocab object, using the constructor function created above
    const newVocab = new Vocab(formObj.word, formObj.meaning, formObj.notes);
    
    myVocab.push(newVocab);

    // clear form after submission
    event.target.reset();

    // save the form submission data to localStorage
    saveData();

    return newVocab;
}

// this function will run every time the submit button is clicked
form.addEventListener('submit', function(event) {

    // first, call the addVocab function, store its result in a new variable
    const addedVocab = addVocab(event);

    // second, create the DOM elements needed to display the vocab on a card
    const newVocabCard = document.createElement('div');
    newVocabCard.classList.add('vocab-card');
    newVocabCard.style.cssText = `
        padding: 10px;
        border: 3px solid black;
        color: var(--drkPurple);
        background-color: white;
        border-radius: 5px;
        box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);`

    const vocabWord = document.createElement('p');
    vocabWord.innerText = addedVocab.word;

    const vocabMeaning = document.createElement('p');
    vocabMeaning.innerText = addedVocab.meaning;

    const vocabNotes = document.createElement('p');
    vocabNotes.innerText = addedVocab.notes;

    newVocabCard.appendChild(vocabWord);
    newVocabCard.appendChild(vocabMeaning);
    newVocabCard.appendChild(vocabNotes);

    vocabGrid.appendChild(newVocabCard);
});
```

I am a total JavaScript beginner and this is my first time trying to use an API so the simplest way to solve this would be best for my learning! Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can view the contents of localStorage using the browser's Developer Tools.

Comment: Don't use `myVocab.push()` when fetching from `localStorage`. Just myVocab = JSON.parse(storedData)`

Comment: `loadData()` needs to display all the items that it fetched.

Comment: Take the code from the submit listener that creates the card, and move it into a separate function. Then you can call this function from both the event listener and in a loop from `loadData()`.

Comment: @Barmar thank you for your comments! I made these corrections and was able to accomplish what I wanted with my code. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your data is being saved to localStorage - I verified with the dev tools on your codepen. The issue is you have no code to generate the cards on page load.

What I would suggest is creating a function that accepts a vocab object, and adds a corresponding card to the dom (similar to the code you have in your submit listener).

Up where you call loadData you would then loop over the vocab array and call that function for each item in the array. You can also use this new function in your submit handler to reduce code duplication. Does that make sense?

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions! This gave me a really good start and with some additional tinkering I was able to succeed in getting my data to both save to localStorage as well as continue to display when the page is refreshed. I also figured out how to see in the dev tools where the data is stored.

As someone who is still at the early stages of learning, I really appreciated that your comment gave me just enough information to figure it out without just giving me the code. Thank you!

Comment: @AbigailDawson you're welcome! Glad you got it figured out.